# Git sync repository in two different workspaces(folders) on the same computer

Tags: git, git-pull, pull

I am working on a git repository in which I don't have remote push(write) permission. I need this repo(in sync: same branch, same code) in two different work spaces(cloned into different folders) on same host. One solution is to do the same change at both the places. But this is just duplication of the effort because it will be exactly same change and ultimately I will be pushing these changes to remote from one repo only.
Hence, I wanted to do the following:

1. Do the changes in one workspace followed by local-commit
2. Pull these change into another workspace without pushing these
   changes into remote .

   How can i do this in git.

Thanks,
Shantanu

Comment: Yes. I need this repo in two different folders.

Comment: There are two different services running locally on my box. Both is consuming this repo. I need this change in both the services. Also, these services need to consume this package from their respective worksplaces only.

Comment: oh ok. You can try modifying the origin of one of the repo to your local. But in that case you will loose the git push functionality on one repo, where as the other will have that. is that fine?

Comment: Yes it is. As I said, I need to push to remote from one repo only. Can you please let me know how to do that.

Comment: Set them as remotes so that you can push between them as needed. Even if it's on the same FS, different repos are "remotes" so....

Comment: Could you please let me know the command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do this both are changing the origin of the repo's to point one repo.

Lets assume that your repo is A

once you clone the repo to your local 'first destination', you will have the origin in that repo pointing to your remote, which will be https://github.com..../A.git

Now if you want to clone the repo again to your 'second destination' you can either clone it from the remote or use your local.

1. if you are choosing remote option:
   Then go to the repo and update the  git remote origin to your local repo.

   git remote set-url origin localpath/A.git
2. if you are using local options:
   You don't have to do anything. Just clone properly with the git clone pointing to your local repo. example for windows

   git clone C:\xxxxxx\A\.git

   The above will set the origin to your local repo. So you can go ahead and commit the file in the first cloned location and do a pull from the second cloned location and they will be in sync with each other.

Comment: Really? git can set the origin to a local repo!? I just became aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

All,

For me the repository must start absolutely empty and the files from the 20+ directories must be added from the 1st non-repository directory, then as the additional directories are read their files must then merge with the newly added files in the repository.

Cheers!

TBNK